# Make a monolithic personal config compatible with Prelude and Spacemacs

Tags: init-file, spacemacs, prelude

I'm refactoring my config from a monolithic init file (a .org that is tangled) to something more modular.

In the same time, I am trying out *Prelude* and *Spacemacs*, and I feeling it very likely to use both of them in different context.

As a result I am trying to find a **way to dispatch and structure my original init file in a way that can be easily plugged into both Prelude and Spacemacs**.

- The Spacemacs way uses pushes to create (private) configuration layers. But I'm not sure I could find a way to use them in Prelude. (and I'm not fond of dispatching, dep, function, keybindings into different files)
- The Prelude way puts different *modules* into dedicated files, which you place in folder `personal`.

How can I do this? Has someone already tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to dispatch you configuration in Spacemacs, config.el, keybindings.el and funcs.el are facultative. But for now you have to put ELPA packages in `packages.el` and extensions (i.e. source code not in an ELPA repo) in extensions.el.

I'm no expert with Prelude but here is my guess:

I think you can match Prelude module and Spacemacs layer.

- Create a module for Prelude with the structure of Spacemacs (that is a list for the packages with the associated init functions), the magic variables of Spacemacs mean nothing to Prelude so Prelude won't trigger any of the configuration.
- Then find a way to know if you are in Spacemacs or Prelude and when you are in Prelude call all the init function explicitly which in turn will call all the use-package stuff and your config.
- At last for Spacemacs create a `packages.el` with `load-file` of your Prelude module which has the structure of a Spacemacs packages.el file.